# confusion on continuous extension

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Consider the function $$(x^2-1) \log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$
that is defined on $(-1,1)$. Can we say that this function has a continuous extension at $1$?

I am confused because it is not defined in a neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: For the usual complex definition of log, with $$|x|<1, |\text{arg} x| <\pi  :  (x^2-1)  \log \frac{1+x}{1-x}=(1-x) (1+x) (\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)))$$ its clear that the factor $(1-x)\log(1-x)$ has limit 0 at x=1, the other expressions  well behaved.

Comment: I'm only considering the real logarithm

Answer (score 1):

To make a continuous extension, the fact that it is not defined in a neighborhood does not matter. I guess what troubles you is the fact that the limit to 1 does not exist since the function is not defined on a neighborhood of 1, but since 1 is the least upper bound of your interval, you only need that the limit to $1$ from below of $f(x)$ exists.

If this limit to 1 from below exists and is equal to $l$, then define the function $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in(-1;1)$ and $g(1) = l$ and $g$ will naturally be a continuous extension of $f$.

Hope this helps.